# sscanf variable length string parsing

Tags: c++, c, string, parsing

I have a problem that is probably fairly common and likely has a beautiful hack that I am not aware of. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would enlighten me!

I am using C's sscanf() function to parse input and the format is 
    "%d %d %d %s %d %s %d ..."
    where the first two %d are random ID integers (insignificant) for the string and the third is a count of the number of %d %s combinations to follow.

For instance, "12 34 2 3 yes 2 no" could be a string, where 12 and 34 random are ID's (unimportant to the problem) and 2 specifies the two combinations following of '3 yes' and '2 no'. The 3 preceding 'yes' specifies the length of the string following, and the same is true for the 'no' with a 2 before it. Where we can have a variable number of these combinations following and we want to catch them all with the sscanf.

Does anyone know of any way to do this with sscanf?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the C++ tag is accurate, you probably want to use a `stringstream` instead. It'll make this rather easier.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. Sorry.

Comment: @TimHaggard: Is this a C question or a C++ question? They are different languages.

Comment: @nneonneo: The `scanf` function is part of the C Standard and also part of the C++ Standard.  It is appropriate to tag `scanf()` questions with either or both languages.

Comment: @Ben But depending on which language is used, a good answer would be rather different, which would warrant two different questions/answers. Combining the two doesn't really help imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just parse the string in two (or more) passes. This uses the `%n` format specifier to write the number of bytes processed, so we know where to pick up in subsequent passes:

```
int a, b, n, pos;
const char *buf = "12 34 2 3 yes 2 no";

assert(sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d %n", &a, &b, &n, &pos) == 3);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int cur;

    int x;
    char y[20];

    assert(sscanf(buf+pos, "%d %19s %n", &x, y, &cur) == 2);
    printf("%d %s\n", x, y);
    pos += cur;
}
```

outputs

```
3 yes
2 no
```

Comment: I'd wrap the sscanf's around assert, to make sure I know when the first returns something other than 3 and the second returns something other than 2 respectively. Aside from that, +1 because this is my favourite answer in the realm of C programming.

Comment: Apparently the effect of `%n` on the return value is somewhat undefined (ew). So I will add asserts for `>=3`/`>=2`.

Comment: As an aside, this may in fact be the only time I've ever found `%n` useful (outside of exploiting format string vulnerabilities to write arbitrary data to arbitrary stack addresses).

Comment: No, it's well defined. The C standard says "Execution of a
%n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the
completion of execution of the fscanf function." The `%n` directive will always execute providing the previous directives succeed, which is why I suggested `assert`. Ideally, one would report an error instead of raising an assertion failure. However, including error reporting code in such an example takes the focus away from the direction of the solution. `assert` will hopefully bring that focus back, when errors *do* occur.

Comment: `%n` is also useful when you need the number of decimals in an integer. Many people will use code such as `assert(scanf("%d", &val) == 1); do { decimal_count++; val /= 10; } while (val > 0);` (erroneously, for negative values) when all that is necessary is `assert(scanf("%d%n", &val, &decimal_count) == 1);`.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Check out [Technical Corrigendum 1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/tc1.htm), Page 138. It says that in the call `i = sscanf("123", "%d%n%n%d", &d1, &n1,&n2, &d2);` that `i` gets the value 3.

Comment: That TC is for the C89 standard and I'm quoting from the C11 standard. Additionally, I'd suggest that's an error.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. They've fixed that error in future standards. So it is now well-defined. (This is what I get from reading old spec documents...)

Comment: It was well defined, back then, too. [The C89 standard](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) mirrors the C99 and C11 text I quoted earlier. The [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standards contain that example with "The value 1 is assigned to i" instead of 3. I'd suggest that the example was erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

There's no convenient way to do this with just `sscanf`.  You'd need to dynamically generate the format string itself, *before* passing it to `sscanf`.

You might want to consider writing a specialized parsing routine for this where you call `sscanf` in a loop, or more preferably (since you specify the C++ tag) using an `std::istringstream` in a loop.

Comment: I meant sscanf. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ssprintf() is used to generate string, not parse it. You should use sscanf. I do not know hwo to finish it in one sscanf(). But you can do it in a loop as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int choice_id, count;
    char choice[20],id_1[20],id_2[20], count_str[20], choice_id_str[20];
    int index;
    char *input = "12 34 2 3 yes 2 no";

    sscanf(input, "%s %s %s", id_1, id_2, count_str);
    input += strlen(id_1)+strlen(id_2)+strlen(count_str)+2;
    count = atoi(count_str);
    for(index = 0; index< count; ++index){
        sscanf(input, " %s %s", choice_id_str, choice );
        choice_id = atoi(choice_id_str);
        // Process or store the record
        printf("%d: %s\n",choice_id, choice);
        input += strlen(choice_id_str) + strlen(choice) + 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with gcc (GCC) 4.1.2, and run with Linux. The output is:

```
-bash-3.2$ ./a.out
3: yes
2: no
```

Comment: the input here is the to-parse string, such as "12 34 2 3 yes 2 no"

Comment: It is not clear how to move the pointer. `scanf` may consume an arbitrary amount of the input string.

Comment: That's incorrect...a space in `sscanf` could match an arbitrary amount of whitespace (not just one character).

Comment: I did not notice that. But I think it still works well. I updated my code into full exampel.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a maximum value for the number of %d %s pairs that follow the initial "%d %d %d" header?
There must be since you're putting the values somewhere, perhaps in a 
struct { int i; char s[j]; } a[n]; 
with appropriate j and n sizes.

(BTW, your example uses "%d %d %d %s %d %s %d ..." when the description indicates it should be  "%d %d %d %d %s %d %s %d %s ...", 3 decimals, followed by decimal/string pairs)

If there is a maximum just create a maximized template and test that the return code from sscanf, which should indicate the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, is your 3rd value minus the 3 header items.
If the return code isn't correct when compared to the 3rd int, report a malformed line.

I once made something like this a function so the a[n] was automatic ion the stack and then the function allocated a linked list from the heap for the items sscanf-ed and returned a pointer to the first item.